# Product of the three numbers obtained by rolling three dice. Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

What is the expected value and variance of X, the product of the three numbers obtained by rolling three fair die?

I tried solving this problem by dividing the numbers $\{1,...,216\}$ into primes and composites, but realized there were too many. The hint that was given to me was to use indicators. I can't figure out how.

Comment: Well, since the outcomes of the three die are independent of each other you can get the expectation just by multiplying.  Variance can be done along the same lines.

Comment: Side note:  the sample space is really not so big here (though maybe a bit too big for pencil and paper).  Brute force is not terribly difficult and you can use that to check the answer derived from independence.

Comment: Would (7/2)^3 be the answer for expectation, then?
I think I confused myself because 1, 1, 4 and 2, 2, 1 were different events that lead to the same outcome of 4.

Comment: Yes, that's the expectation.  As I say...do it by brute force to check.  It's good practice in any case.

Comment: I have incorporated exact answers for the expectation and standard deviation into the simulation in my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we're down to the 'good practice' of brute force, in which
(for me anyhow) bookkeeping errors might creep in. So I'll provide 
a simulation which may be accurate enough to help catch mistakes.
About three digits of accuracy for $E(X)$ and $SD(X).$

```
set.seed(421);  m=10^7
x = replicate( m, prod(sample(1:6, 3, repl=T))  )
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 42.86178  # aprx E(X) = (7/2)^3 = 42.875
## 40.62558  # aprx SD(X) = 40.62621
sqrt((91/6)^3 - (7/2)^6)
## 40.62621
```

Numerators of 216 (2nd row):

```
 round(table(x)*216/m)
 x
 1   2   3   4   5   6   8   9  10  12  15  16  18  20  24  25  27  30  32  36 
 1   3   3   6   3   9   7   3   6  15   6   6   9   9  15   3   1  12   3  12 

40  45  48  50  54  60  64  72  75  80  90  96 100 108 120 125 144 150 180 216 
 6   3   9   3   3  12   1   9   3   3   6   3   3   3   6   1   3   3   3   1
```